# MVC 3 Wizard via JavaScript unsafe?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I stepped over the following tutorial:
http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx

Since it looks pretty nice, I'm asking myself if making the complete wizard in JavaScript just like that is a good/safe idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in that as long as you are using **POST**  **HTTP** methods for save/delete data operations. But i would always make the app to work in a non-javascript version and once it is done, add the javascript fancy version like the ajaxified wizard.

Comment: I would have prefered the non-javascript way but since I'm having trouble with it I gave it up for now and thought this example is pretty good explained which would be perfect, I just had some doubts about security stuff. Thanks for your answer, I guess it's just fine then. :)